# returning a string from a class object with __str__

Tags: python, string, class

Im having trouble with this fifo-queue program, i've worked out most of the code, which looks like this:

```
class fifoQueue:

    __L = []
        def __init__(self):
        self.__L = []


    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__L)


    def empty(self):
        if len(q) == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False


    def enqueue(self, e):
        self.__L.insert(0, e)
            return self.__L


    def dequeue(self):
        if self.empty():
            self.__L = [e]
        else:
            return self.__L.pop()

    def __str__(self):
        return "'" + str(self.__L) + "'"
```

the problem I have is with the __ str __(self) function, what I want it to do is to return my list self.__L with "'" if I call print(str(q)), but if I only call print(q) I want it to return the list. Right now I get the same output for both print(q) and print(str(q)).

```
(print(str(q)) returns '[31.0]'
print(q) returns '[31.0]'
```

whereas I would like it to return

```
str(q) returns '[31.0]' or print(str(q)) returns '[31.0]'
print(q) returns [31.0]
```

I come from a background in mathematics and this is one of the first languages im learning so I apologize if this is very basic.
This is an assignment where I have to only use __ str __ to accomplish this, no additional functions can be created. 
Any directions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe you've misunderstood your assignment.

Comment: `print` calls `__str__`.

Comment: `__L = []` and `self.__L = []` ouch same variable name but one is class-variable the other is instance variable...

Comment: Both `print(obj)` and `str(obj)` end up calling `obj.__str__`. BTW I think your `dequeue` method will crash if your queue is empty because `e` is not defined.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using two underscores in front of your attribute name? I.e: `self.__L`?

Answer (score 1):

The __str__ method should be as follows:

```
 def __str__(self):
      return str(self.__L)    # delegate to built-in function (no concatenation with quote)
```

Or:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '{self.__L !s}'.format(self.__L)    # string formatting
```